# powershell: Get Distribution Group Members list with multiple domains and nested groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How to get Distribution Group Members list with multiple domains and nested groups.

***`Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "MygroupName" -Recursive`*** is not working since it has multiple domains.

I need to output useralias and groupname. can someone help me on this?

Comment: That should work for multiple domains if you have the right permission - what error are you getting?

Comment: Here is the error message get-adgroupmember : An operations error occurred
At line:5 char:1
+ get-adgroupmember -Identity GroupName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (GroupName:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8224,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember

Comment: As @Itchydon said, this is most likely due to access issues you have on other domain(s). I would recommend trying your script (`Get-ADGroupMember`) on a group that only has groups and users that are part of the same domain that you do have access to. If that works, then you know its something with access, not the script.